# Why when a task is marked as “Stalled” the following tasks can't automatically processed?

Tags: control-panel, tasks, cron, stalled-tasks

This is annoying to have to click on “**Try again**” to unlock the queued tasks. This could leads to dozen and dozen of stucked tasks that usually could be processed without any problem (like the *Generating search keywords* tasks).

I know there are [recommandations](https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks) about how to avoid stuck stacks, and we have setup a lot of these. But from time to time, we still face tasks marked as “**Stalled**” (and sometimes not) on several websites.

I know cron jobs using [runTasksAutomatically setting](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#runTasksAutomatically) or [taskrunner plugin](https://gitlab.com/24hoursmedia/craft2-plugins/craft2-taskrunner) could also avoid this by calling the *runPendingTasks* at a more regular interval than connect to the Control Panel from time to time.

There's probably a good answer for that, but why when there's a task marked as “**Stalled**” in the Control Panel, this one is not ignored to automatically let the following tasks processing? And is there a way to automatically ignored these tasks marked as **“Stalled”**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why when there's a task marked as “Stalled” in the Control Panel, this one is not ignored to automatically let the following tasks processing?

Because tasks behind it might rely on the data that the successful completion of the stalled task would generate.

> And is there a way to automatically ignored these tasks marked as “Stalled”?

You could probably hack it somehow, but I wouldn't recommend it.  It's best to fix the underlying reason the task stalled in the first place.